On reproducing the Poincare section figure in a paper by Sato, Akiyama and Doyne Farmer
I am trying to reproduce Figure 1 in the paper "Chaos in learning a simple two-person game" (English) Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 99, No. 7, 4748-4751 (2002) (MR1895748, Zbl 1015.91014), by Sato, Akiyama, and Doyne Farmer, showing the Poincare section of a two-player replicator dynamics in rock-paper-scissors game.
I am not able to reproduce the clean, axis aligned orbits. I'm not sure if this is happening because I'm not using a fourth order symplectic integrator or because of some other issue in my code. My code is available here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! For comparison, you can see below the relevant figures:

Figure in the paper,
My figure.


this seems off-topic here; indeed you want to use a symplectic integrator for reliable results, as explained in https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/29149 --- that site seems more on-topic for your question.
